# This setting is managed by your domain administrator

Tags: security, google-workspace-for-business

I'm following [Let less secure apps access your account - Google Account Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?authuser=1), specifically "Option 2", however when I click on [Less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps), I get following message:

> This setting is managed by your domain administrator.

I *am* the domain administrator, *where* is this setting exactly? I can't find it(

Please advise.

Comment: What sort of device are you using?

Comment: Go here and toggle this " https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/116251/this-setting-is-managed-by-your-domain-administrator " off

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the G Suite Administrator Help:

Sign in to your Google Admin console.
Sign in using an administrator account.

From the Admin console dashboard, go to `Security` and then `Basic settings`.

To see `Security` on the dashboard, you might have to click `More controls` at the bottom.

Under `Less secure apps`, select `Go to settings for less secure apps.`

In the subwindow, select the `Enable access to less secure apps for all users` radio button.

Answer (score 0):

This is the URL- https://admin.google.com/ac/security/lsa

1. you need to go to admin console
2. choose security in sidebar
3. choose less secure app, change the radio button to allow

[image: image according to admin console as of 2021]